# My iPhone, Macbook and Laptop won't connect to 192.168.1.*

Tags: macos, networking, windows-xp, macbook, local

Previously I could connect perfectly with my iphone to my web server on 192.168.1.* but since I got a MacBook, I now can't even connect my iphone to either of the computers.

I can connect to the wifi hub on my iphone, I can connect to the wifi hub on all the computers including my phone.

Neither of my computers nor my iphone 5 can communicate with each other.

What has happened?

I've tried number of different local web servers, even tried the osx web server, but my iphone just wont connect to any.

Comment: [originally posted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710175/my-iphone-wont-connect-to-192-168-1#19710175http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710175/my-iphone-wont-connect-to-192-168-1#19710175) (please flag for migration the next time)

Comment: Sounds like the address of the webserver has changed because of the new device.

Comment: how do I fix this?

Comment: Look up your router's documentation on setting up a static IP address.

Comment: I looked at the hubs documents, and it said incare your unable to connect, restart hub, and I clicked restart and it worked, all devices are connecting, thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the IPs of all the devices on your network?

My suspicion is that the IP for your Web Server has been taken by another device, in which case you may want to set a static IP for your webserver via your router if it supports it.

Comment: I restarted the hub, and its backup and working now, thankyou.

Comment: Up vote to 1Rabbit as they were onto the answer too.....